# How to rearrange this matrix equation to find x

Tags: matrices

The equation is:
$$ A=x^{T}Bx $$
How to get matrix $x$ knowing $A$ and $B$? Should I somehow divide both sides by $B^{-1}?$

A and B as well as x are square matrices. A and B are symetric with positive diagonal values.

Comment: If $B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ then $A\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times 1}\cong \mathbb{R}$

Comment: x is a matric not a vector. I have edited my question.

Comment: You need more restrictions on $A$ and $B$ to guarantee a solution. For example: if everything is $1\times 1$, and $A=1$, $B=-1$ then it can't be done over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The asnwer has been edited. What about now?

Comment: Positive entries on the diagonal does not seem to me to be enough. Have you heard of real quadratic forms? Sylvester's Law of Inertia?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have a unique solution. For example if $A=B=I$ then we just need
$$x^Tx=I$$
so $x$ can be any orthogonal matrix.

Answer (score -1):

Since we know $A$ and $B$, one straightforward way is to just matrix multiply using $x$ as a matrix of variables, then use linear algebra to solve the equation.

Depending on whether some matrices are diagonal or orthonormal, we can do some additional tricks or even perform numerical computations, but without knowing the kind of the matrices, it's hard to say which way to go.

Note that matrix multiplication is not commutative, so you can't simply multiply $B^{-1}$ to eliminate $B$ in the middle.

Comment: A and B are sumetric, if it changes anything. Could you write down the exact matrix equation for x?

Comment: The equations we get for the elements of $X$ are not linear.